# How to declare typescript type within a js array map?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to make the following mapping with the js array map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
x =  state.users.map(({id, firstName, lastName}) => 
    ({id, value: `${firstName} ${lastName}`}));
```

However, I am getting the following typescript error `Binding element 'X' implicitly has an any type` for each of the properties e.g. id, firstname etc

If I try to assign a type to the properties like so:

```
x =  state.users.map(({id: number, firstName: string, lastName: string}) => 
    ({id, value: `${firstName} ${lastName}`}));
```

these are allocated as values not types.

How can I correctly assign a type to a property within a map function?

Comment: `state.users` have to be typed. TS doesn't now what do you store there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put any:

```
x =  state.users.map(({id, firstName, lastName}: any) => 
    ({id, value: `${firstName} ${lastName}`}));
```

or with an explicit type:

```
x =  state.users.map(({id, firstName, lastName}: {id: string, firstName: string, lastName: string}) => 
    ({id, value: `${firstName} ${lastName}`}));
```